# docker on ubuntu 18.04 - strange loss of connectivity error: Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking

I am having quite a strange docker container behavior on my ubuntu 18.04.

Essentially, I have a docker postgres container running with the typical port forwarding configuration.

```
docker run --rm --detach -v /home/userHome/Dev/DockerVolumes/postgres_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name postgres11-instance1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=adminadmin -p 5432:5432 --network pgnetwork postgres:11.5
```

Very basic command.
Running database with all default settings.
The password is your typical adminadmin no security set at all.

Triggering postgres on my mac works flawlessly.
On ubuntu the system behaves in a cahotic manner...

Sometimes, when the postgres container starts running everything is working perfectly.
You can browse the database using pgadmin.
You can, if you want, try to telenet localhost 5432 to see that you are able to establish a stable tcp/ip connection to the target port. In short, things work the way you would expect.

But sometimes, on my ubuntu, the postgres database mysteriously stops being reachable.
And the first impression would be that blame lays on the docker network stack and nowhere else, since from within the container, the postgres service is running just fine.

To exaplain this better. If I try to play with my running docker postgres by doing something like follwoing:

```
docker exec -it postgres-instance1 /bin/sh
```

I am able to hook a terminal to the running container.
And from within the container, i am able to connect to any database. Test different psql commands...
I have also tried to, just for the sake of trying, run apt-get install telnet. And from withing the container image, I try to telnet localhsot 5432 and I see that from withing the container the tcp/ip connection is accepted and not immediately closed.

The behavior really is that from the ubuntu host machine, or any other machine in the network for that matter, for whatever reason that i cannot explain, somtimes the command "telnet locahost 5432" immediately stops telling me "Connection closed by foreign host".

It goes from working to not working ... just like that.

I sometimes see something similar with a nexus image.
If telnet localhost 8081, where 8081 is my host portwording to the nexus image. I sometimes see the first attempt to establish this connection immediately fail with the same error message.  But then, on my second attempt to connect to the socket, the tcp ip connection holds and is no longer closed immediately.

On my postgres image for whatever it keeps on failing.
And the stranges thing is that without needing to restart my docker service or stopping any container, somehow, the networking goes back to working if interact with the nexus container.

So for example, look at this strange terminal interaction.
All of the telnet commands you see written bellow they are being done on the ubuntu host.
The localhost 5432 should be port forwarded to a perfectly functional postgres container.
The localhost 8081 should be port forwarded to a perfectly function nexus container.

```
someuser@someuser-somecomputer:~$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.9, build 1752eb3
someuser@someuser-somecomputer:~$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
someuser@someuser-somecomputer:~$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
someuser@someuser-somecomputer:~$ telnet localhost 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

sfafas
HTTP/1.1 400 No URI
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 49
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)

<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: No URI</pre>Connection closed by foreign host.
someuser@someuser-somecomputer:~$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

What the strange console interaction is showing is that i had been trying to do a stable telnet connection to postgres and hitting the wall of connection closed by remote host.
OK...
Then I tried connection to the nexus machine that also is running on the same docker pgnetwork and have no problem connection to port forwarded socket 8081.

Then I finally write some rubish via the tcp ip socket to nexus machine.
Get some HTTP error saying that I am sending rubish requests.
And finally my postgres machine is again reachable.

The routing table is perfectly normal.
IT has route 172.19.0.0/16 put it to some docker network card called br-e29..whatever.

So the route to the postgres machine routing with ip 172.19.0.2 is the same as to the nexus machine that has ip ending .5.

So it really seems to make no sense to me what I see.

The same phenomena i have never encountered either on windows or on mac.

I also seem to not encounter this problem on any of the other containers running on ubuntu, such as for example the  pg-admin.
Intuitively, one would think, if all of your other containers like nexus and pg-admin are always reachable and manifest no problems on the port fowarding, the problem must lay on the postgres container itself and not on the docker networking...

But if that were to be the case, then it must mean that for whatever reason, postgres withing the docker container is deciding to temporarily suspend access to itself via remote connections.
The official docker comes configure to allow all remote connections...

My guess is the issue is perhaps the postgres process on the container.
From withing bash session in the container you will not notice any flaws.
The socket is there, the socket is listening, you can telenet from withing the container itself and you can do any "psql" command you wish.

So the logical database process itself is running just fine...
And since under normal circunstances literally any computer on the network can do whatever it wants on this pogres machine (literally no ip restriction anybody can do whatever it wants to this db).
That makes it strange that the postgres process would out of the blue decide to start filtering some requests out and immediately reject incoming connections.

But for now I am clueless to the reason of this phenomena...
When it happens, and i refuse to restart my ubuntu or the docker process, the issue takes some time to pass until the db is accepting again outside world connections. The problem goes away just as mysteriously as it comes.

Does anyone have any sort of idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Situation seems to have improved after i have done docker network -rm pgnetwork followed by docker network create pgnetwork. It is as if the network was corrupted. Going to keep monitoring to see if the situtation returns back or if docker is functioning normally again. While the situation was happening, before i removed the old pgnetwork, i could monitor with netstat that no tcp ip connection requests arrived inside of the docker machine when the siutation was happening. So it was not the postgres process rejecting request, it was the pgnetwork not being routed the requests apparently.